# Scroll an iframe without having to mouse over it

Tags: iframe, scroll, mouseover

I have an iframe that I use to display the main content of my webpage; however, I would like to make the IFRAME scroll regardless of where the mouse is pointing. I do not want my visitors to be confused by not being able to scroll unless their mouse is over the iframe. Is this possible? To scroll the iframe with the mouse hovering anywhere over the body?

I won't link any code, because the only relevant code I have is the < iframe>< /iframe> tag.

(the body itself is not scrollable with scrollbars hidden)

Comment: I can't find ANYTHING on google or this website related to this :(

Comment: I think this would be possible using javascript somehow...I am not too knowledgable about JS to create it though. Something with defining the whole < body>'s mouseover area to be linked to the iframe, so that scrolling the mousewheel outside the frame boundaries still scrolls it.

Comment: I guess I would need someone to write me a code that basically says: "body.hover (or body onmouseover) scroll iframeid" or something like that haha, like I said i fail at JS.

Comment: I would use jQuery's [**.load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load) to load a page into a div of my current page and make it scrollable instead of an iframe that is a window on its own.

Comment: does this mean I can just .load the entire iframe contents into a div? and would that solve the "scroll this no matter where your mouse pointer is?"

Comment: If the page you are loading is from the same domain then by .load() it becomes part of your primary page, as if you put it there from the first place. But I must have misinterpreted your question as you are most probably loading a page in your iframe that has its own css and javascript etc. If that is so the .load() I suggested won't do much good.

Comment: it IS part of my page, meaning I have control over all content inside it, and I can re-define the style of the iframe contents from the main page if need be; I just dont know how to properly implement that code and dont know if that would solve my scroll-anywhere problem

Comment: Can you tell me if and what programming language you are using to create the page with (ie. PHP) as well as why you chose to have an iframe in the first place? I wouldn't like to divert you from what you originally planned to achieve.

Comment: Im just using HTML and CSS, the iframe in question is contained in a couple div's and only takes up about 50-60% of the browser window. I have a set style that I am using for the main page, and I was originally going to use a scrollable div but there were too many cross-browser limitations as to how that worked and an iframe was just the better option.

Comment: you can view the site here if you like: www.tomiboy.com - the main scrollable content is an iframe, but it is important to me that visitors dont get confused by not being able to scroll unless the mouse is hovering over the iframe.

Comment: (also dont hate on my html! i still use tables, which is very oldschool but that basically defines my style of coding, haha)

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I put together a rather quick and dirty solution for this which includes the following steps:

- Add an "id" to your `<iframe>` element. (In my example I used `id="myFrame"`)
- Attach the **jQuery Mousewheel** plugin to the header of your html page along with the latest jQuery.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/master/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
```

- Finally add the following javascript code at the end of the html body or **after** the iframe itself.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var scrolloffset = 30;  // amount of scrolling per mousewheel step

    var myFrame = $('#myFrame');  // the iframe ID
    var frameScrollPosition = 0;

    $(window).mousewheel(function(event,delta){

        // reset stored offset so that it matches with iframe's
        frameScrollPosition = myFrame.contents().scrollTop();

        var frameHeight = myFrame.contents().height() - myFrame.height();

        if(delta > 0){
            var newPosition = frameScrollPosition - scrolloffset;
        } else {
            var newPosition = frameScrollPosition + scrolloffset;
        }

        if(newPosition < 0){
            newPosition = 0;
        }

        if(newPosition >= frameHeight){
            newPosition = frameHeight;
        }

        frameScrollPosition = newPosition;
        myFrame.contents().scrollTop(frameScrollPosition);

    });
</script>
```

Make sure you [**download**](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/downloads) the plugin and not call it from github like me. It was just for testing and proof of concept.

Comment: Did what you said but nothing different is happening :( Tested in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. Did this work for you when you tested it?

Comment: Something that might be conflicting with this code is that the iFrame itself is not scrollable- I am using the scrollbars from the source of the iframe instead of making the iframe itself just scroll the content of its source. Could that be the issue? (If I change it so that the iframe scrolls instead, I lose my custom scroll bar in some browsers.)

Comment: (sorry for the delayed response, I was on vacation!) Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @TommyBlackburn Here is my temporary test http://alderis.net/iframe.html as proof. IE has issues with it (not surprised). On other browsers it works fine. In general, iframes are a pain to work with. Please make all changes on your page again as per my instructions for me to see what's wrong.

Comment: I can NOT figure this out...after hours of testing, even copying your exact example to my computer for testing, it does not work. It works for me on the link you provided, but when I copy EVERYTHING you did to a folder on my computer, it doesnt work. Im stumped.

Comment: the only thing I can fathom making this not work are possible security issues with running scripts that are on my machine instead of on the web...which doesnt make sense, because the other scripts on my website run fine offline. /headache

Comment: maybe its something weird with macbook. lol i just DON'T get it.

Comment: just tested on a PC; yours only half works in firefox- the scrolling OUTSIDE the iframe works, but when the mouse is inside the iframe it doesnt scroll. On mine, there is no scrolling at all.

Comment: @TommyBlackburn Javascript has a [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and therefore does not work when you have an iframe linking with a page outside your own domain, such as mine, since you copied it exactly. I used mine as an example. You must change the iframe source to a page of your own domain and see. The same domain that the script runs from, otherwise javascript cannot access the DOM of the external page for security reasons.

Comment: Thats interesting...it should still work within my own file structure though (not your example, but the code you provided.) I updated a page of my site so you can take a look: www.tomiboy.com/reeltest.html. Still not working no matter what I do to it.

Comment: @TommyBlackburn This has taken more time than expected. Tables make hell lot of a mess. Your CSS is dirty as well. When your page is loaded, the javascript that you use for the vertical scrollbar sets the height of the page to the same height as the iframe that includes it. As a result my code wants to scroll the page, but the page has no ability to scroll as its the same size each time with the iframe. So the thing in your way is the scrollbar functionality. My code works as expected on your page too, when I remove the special scrollbar. My final suggestion, **table-less** design, no iframes.

Comment: i fixed it! you were right- it was the IFRAME scrollbar code that was getting in the way, and it must be uploaded to my server for the code to work at all (wouldnt work straight off my hard drive.) Once I deleted the iframe source code, it worked perfectly.

Thanks for all your help Alderis, i know my code is a mess but this ultimately works exactly how I want it to :)